# How can I prevent these ranges from overlapping in Java?

Tags: java

I am writing some code in java which checks through an array of 51 objects called `beatArr` which are circles which move from right to left towards a player positioned at x:200px. I want to make it so that the player is awarded points or deducted points based on the timing of their button presses compared to the position of a beat, and so far I have the following:

[image: game running]

```
 public static void hit(){
        //Method for player to hit the beat
        for (Beat beat : Game.beatArr) {
            if (beat.getX() <= 220 && beat.getX() >=150){
                score+=100;
                System.out.println("Perfect+ "+score);
            }

            else if (beat.getX() <= 250 && beat.getX() >=100) {
                score += 100;
                System.out.println("Good "+score);
            }

            else if(beat.getX() <=99 && beat.getX()>=0 | beat.getX() >250){
                score -=50;
                System.out.println("Miss " + score);
            }
        }
```

This method causes several problems as the ranges overlap and so on a button press something like this usually gets outputted:

```
Miss 3000
Good 3100
Good 3200
```

Whereas I want it to only check a single position at a time really such as the one closest to the player for example or an iterator for checking the object at a given position in the array which I am not sure about the syntax for. So far I've tried changing the order of the checks to see if that affected anything which it unfortunately did not.

Testing out replacing `beat.getX()` with `Game.beatArr[counter].getX()` Where counter = 0 for now.

It seems to check the position of the 1 beat 51 times, the full length of the array for some reason. Output:

```
Good 100
Good 200
Good 300
Good 400
Good 500
Good 600
Good 700
Good 800
Good 900
Good 1000
Good 1100
Good 1200
Good 1300
Good 1400
Good 1500
Good 1600
Good 1700
Good 1800
Good 1900
Good 2000
Good 2100
Good 2200
Good 2300
Good 2400
Good 2500
Good 2600
Good 2700
Good 2800
Good 2900
Good 3000
Good 3100
Good 3200
Good 3300
Good 3400
Good 3500
Good 3600
Good 3700
Good 3800
Good 3900
Good 4000
Good 4100
Good 4200
Good 4300
Good 4400
Good 4500
Good 4600
Good 4700
Good 4800
Good 4900
Good 5000
Good 5100
```

Creation of beatArr:

```
 public static Beat [] beatArr = new Beat [51];

  int startingPoint = 800;
        //For loop 51 times
        for(int i=0;i<=50;i++){
            //modifier to start position to create differing gaps between beats
            int startModifier = random.nextInt(50);
            // instantiates objects into an array for each iteration of the loop
            handler.addObject(beatArr[i] = new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat));
            //redefines the starting point for each beat
            startingPoint = startingPoint+50+startModifier;

        }
```

Comment: You are testing every single "beat" you have for overlap. Shouldn't you be only testing the first "beat"? (Aka.: remove the loop completely and use only `Game.beatArr[0]`)

Comment: Or keep an index into the array, pointing to the current beat.  Them only check how close the player is to the current beat.  Outside this check you should set the index to the current beat according the the time.

Comment: This is the line of thinking I'm currently on, I'm not really sure of the syntax though, currently trying out something along the lines of Game.beatArr[counter].getX() which seems to be allowed

Comment: @SourOddity This is unrelated to your query but the score incremented for both `"Perfect+ "` and `"Good "` is same. Is it intentional?

Comment: `left towards a player at 200px` doesn't make sense as pixels are not a rate. It is also unclear (at least to me) what problem(s) you are having.  Is `beatArr` a list of user inputs?  How does checking their ranges associate with anything that is advancing across the screen.   A [mre] would certainly help here.

Comment: @PalLaden yeah the score is just like that for now, I will adjust it later just want it working first

Comment: @WJS By player at 200px I mean that the player is just static like their positions is x:200px. beatArr is an array of objects called beats which are circles which move towards the player, I'm checking the range of their x when the player presses spacebar to decide how many, if any points to award.

Comment: Where are you doing this check?  Are you using a button to capture the event?  And how are the objects triggered to move across the screen?  I keep thinking that if any of this is done inside the Event Dispatch Thread then user input and any other movement may be halted while the `beatArr` is being interated.  Also, are you trying to detect when the passing objects provide maximum coverage over the fixed one?

Comment: Yes in an inputhandler class the method is called when the player presses spacebar: 
 `if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player){

if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) Player.hit();`

Also, I'm looking to check where the passing objects cover the player object, which is not currently right, I'll adjust it once it works though

Comment: So this implies that the user gets to hit the space bar as often as they want.  So for a given moving object,  they could actually get a complete mixture of results. If they hit it fast enough they could get say 5+ goods for a single object before it is no longer  relevant.  Or do you want to limit it to one hit attempt per moving object?

Comment: 1 hit per object would be best, I had thought of that problem before, so my overall aim was to make it so there is for example a "current beat" potentially in a queue as suggested in the below answer, and make it so once the player misses or hits the beat it is removed from the game

Comment: Then use a linked list to hold the objects.  And don't iterate.  Just check the one at the head and once "processed" delete it.  If the user hits too fast, bad on them.  New objects can be added at the tail.  Adding and removing like this is much more efficient in a linked list than doing so from an array based data structure.   Or  preserve it some way so multiple players can play.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll have a look at implementing it. as you may have guessed though I'm quite new at java so may take some time.

Answer (score 1):

> array of 51 objects called `beatArr`

I believe a [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) would serve your purpose much better.

```java
    public static void hit(){
        //Method for player to hit the beat
        if (Game.beatArr.size()>0) {
            Beat beat = beatArr.remove();//use add() when inserting Beats into beatArr
            if (beat.getX() <= 220 && beat.getX() >=150) {
                score += 100;
                System.out.println("Perfect+ " + score);
            }
        
            else if (beat.getX() <= 250 && beat.getX() >=100) {
                score += 75;
                System.out.println("Good " + score);
            }
        
            else if(beat.getX() <=99 && beat.getX()>=0 || beat.getX() >250){
                score -= 50;
                System.out.println("Miss " + score);
            }
        }
        else {//No beats hence "Miss!"
            score -= 50;
            System.out.println("Miss " + score);
        }
    }
```

This function does the following:

1. Checks overlap of the earliest beat with the white circle.
2. Every time the user attempts to hit, the earliest circle is removed.
3. If there are no beats, it is a `"Miss"`.

**EDIT**: New suggestions based on updates to question.

Instead of

```java
public static Beat [] beatArr = new Beat [51];
```

try

```
public static Queue<Beat> beatArr = new LinkedList<>();
```

You will also have to change

```java
handler.addObject(beatArr[i] = new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat));
```

to

```java
freshBeat = new Beat(startingPoint,300,ID.Beat);
beatArr.add(freshBeat);
handler.addObject(freshBeat);
```

Comment: Is there anything else I need to do with beatArr to convert it to a queue here? The documentation linked is slightly confusing me , but replacing the hit() method with your answer, beatArr.size() and Beat beat = beatArr.pop() are both giving errors. I'll add the creation of beatArr to the question too.

Comment: I know the OP did this but don't use `|`.  Otherwise, it can force checks that don't need to be done.  Use `||` to short circuit OR based checks.

Comment: @WJS Didn't notice. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @SourOddity [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is just an Interface. You must decide which queue implementation you need. For unsynchronized operations, I would recommend [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

Comment: thanks, having a look at ArrayDeque now, so will I need to create a new class for this and can I use it with my existing array? sorry for the confusion here.